# To test whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+2}{2^n+3}\sin\left[(n+\frac12)\pi\right]$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

To determine whether the following sequence converges or divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+2}{2^n+3}\sin\left[(n+\frac12)\pi\right]$$

I don't know which test to use here, but my guess is it may be a comparison test but how to determine which series to use?

Comment: $|\sin x| \leq 1$ for any real $x$, use this

Comment: $\sin (n + 1/2) \pi = (-1)^n$

Comment: For what it's worth, the series does converge absolutely, so the fact that it's alternating is just a cherry on top

Comment: That $2^n$ in the denominator eats everything and guarantees absolute convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: I assume you mean $$\sin\left[(n+1/2)\pi\right]=(-1)^{n}$$

By using this you can see that this is an alternating series. Use the [Leibniz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) to rule out convergence.

Comment: oops..I didn't see that..thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

The absolute convergence and hence the convergence follows easily using asymptotic comparison

$$\left\vert\frac{n+2}{2^n+3}\sin\left[(n+\frac12)\pi\right]\right\vert=\frac{n+2}{2^n+3}=o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right), \text{where} \;n\to \infty$$